# display sha1 password from mysql as plain text

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, sha1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting SHA1 to normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339117/converting-sha1-to-normal-form)

How can i display passwords stored in sha1 format in plain text on page?

essentially how to decrypt passwords from sha1 to plain text?

thanks,

Comment: sha1, md5, other hashing algorithms are intentionally one-way only.  Their purpose is to create a hashed string that _cannot be reversed/decoded_ back to the original input.  The same input string will always produce the same hash, but cannot ever be reversed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't since it's not encryption but hashing. It's one-way, not two-ways like encryption is.

Answer (score 0):

It's hash function which is not for encryption/decryption.